# Portable and Secure Document Repository

Tags: portable, document-management

I'm trying to find a document manager/repository (WinXP) that can be used from a USB disk. I would like a tool that will allow you to add all documents into a single repository (or a secure file system). Ideally you would login to this portable application to add or retrieve a document and document shouldn't be accessible outside of the application.

I have found an application called Benubird Pro (app is portable) that allows you to add files to a single repository, but downsides are that it is not secure and the repository is always stored on the PC and not on the USB disk.

Are you able to recommend any other applications?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/), seems like it would do *most* of what you're after. You can store the encrypted file system on a USB drive easily enough and then mount it as a drive (after supplying the key, of course).

> Main Features:
>
> - Creates a virtual encrypted disk    within a file and mounts it as a real 
>     disk.
> - Encrypts an entire partition or    storage device such as USB flash
>     drive or hard drive.
> - Encrypts a partition or drive where    Windows is installed (pre-boot
>     authentication).
> - Encryption is automatic, real-time    (on-the-fly) and transparent.
> - Parallelization and pipelining allow    data to be read and written
>     as fast    as if the drive was not
>     encrypted.
> - Provides plausible deniability, in    case an adversary forces you to
>     reveal the password:
> - Hidden volume (steganography) and    hidden operating system.
> - Encryption algorithms: AES-256,    Serpent, and Twofish. Mode of
>     operation: XTS.